# Changing value in html table dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an html table where i retrieve data from a database using PHP. The table is quite simple, i have three fields: `Name`, `Quantity` and `Price`. At the end of the table i have an additional field, `Subtot`, that shows the final cost `(SumOfAllItems(Quantity*Price))`.

I need to be able to change the "Quantity" value in each row and the "`Subtot`" should update accordingly. I also need to be able to set min/max value the user can use to update the cell.

I was thinking to add something like a button or any kind of list/input by the "`Quantity`" value in each row.

I think i need to use javascript but i am not sure, any suggestion is welcome. 
Following my code.

Thanks

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price<th>
 </tr>
<?php
while($row2 = $result->fetch_assoc())
{?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row2["Name"] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row2["Quantity"] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row2["Price"]?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
  $subtot = $subtot + ($row2["Price"] * $row2["Quantity"])
 } ?>
<td></td>
<td><b>Subtot.</b></td>
<td><b><?php echo $subtot2 ." Euro"; $tot = $subtot1 + $subtot2;?> </b></td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you can use jQuery or javascript.

Comment: But to be more productive. In order to make any client side changes to your webapplication you will need javascript yes. Lookup how to target DOM elements, read their values, or put new values inside of them. Let us know what you tried and if you still struggle we will gladly assist you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work, however i do not recommend this method (any method btw) without any validation on server side.

You need this on top of your php file:

```
<?php
    $total = 0;
```

Then your table like:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price<th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php while($row2 = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row2['name'] ?></td>
            <td><input class="row" min="0" onchange="myFunction()" data-price="<?php echo $row2['price'] ?>" type="number" value="<?php echo $row2['quantity'] ?>"/></td>
            <td><?php echo $row2['price'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
                $total += $row2['price'] * $row2['quantity'];
            } 
        ?>
        <td></td>
       <td>
            <b>Subtot.</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <b id="total"><?php echo $total; ?></b>
        </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And you need the following script tag:

```
<script>
    function myFunction(){
        var total = 0;
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            total += elements[i].value * elements[i].dataset.price;
        }

        var totalEl = document.getElementById("total");
        totalEl.innerHTML = total;
    }
</script>
```

Again.. this is a very simple solution, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks. Two questions. What do you mean by "validation on server side"? And, this way, you only change the values on screen or the values get updates in the database as well?

Comment: It updates only on screen. You need to post the values to a back-end controller. That is where the validation takes place. You need to check whether the values are valid and the user is not trying to cause any harm. "Never trust your users". After you validate the user input, you can update the DB

Comment: Code doesn't really work..i get an total = NaN anytime i try to change a value

Comment: Maybe you need to parse the price and quantity to an integer / float. It can be done like so: `parseFloat(elements[i].value) * parseFloat(elements[i].dataset.price)` or use `parseInt()` for integers.

[Definition of NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

Comment: Show me what you have done, i'll see if i can see what's going wrong.

Comment: It actually works. Thanks. One last thing. When i update the value by clicking on the up/down arrow, the first time i click, the total price gets updated,  if i click again the total price won't update, i need to press "enter" or click with the mouse somewhere else. Is there any way to make this fully interactive? Anyway, i am going to accept this answer cause it solved the problem. Thank you very much

Comment: That's something that shouldn't happen. Could you change myFunction() to `function myFunction(){ alert('Hi'); }`. It should show an alert everytime you click on the up/down error. If it does show an error, there is something going wrong inside the function, if it doesn't we'll have to debug further.

Comment: Ok, so if i use `function myFunction(){ alert('Hi'); }` it works fine, because a pop-up appears. But if i use `function myFunction(){
console.log(1);  }` again i need to press enter to see the 1 logged in the console after the first time that i click

Comment: I solved the problem using `onclick=myfunction()` instead of `onchange=myfunction()`

Comment: Good to hear! Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!!